# Variable integration limits over real numbers only

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have a simple question regarding this code:

```
Maximize[{Integrate[1/(10 - e)
    Integrate[((x - 5)/(10 - 5))^(9)*5/x, {x, 5, y}]
   , {y, e, 10}], e >= 0, e <= 10}, e]
```

I get the following error message: "Unable to prove that integration limits {10,e} are real. Adding assumptions may help." I tried some things already mentioned in other questions, but I didn't get it to work.
Any tips?

Comment: The first rule of debugging Mathematica: *break the code into pieces and look at what each does separately!*  First do the inner integral.  Look up `Integrate`, `Assumptions` option, and add assumptions as necessary. When everything looks fine, and *only then*, do the outer integral, using the previous result.  Don't write nested integrals, instead re-use the previous output.  Again, use assumptions as appropriate. Repeat the same with Maximize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `Assumptions -> y > 0` in the outer-most integral gives

```
Maximize[{Integrate[1/(10 - e)
        Integrate[((x - 5)/(10 - 5))^(9)*5/x, {x, 5, y}]
      , {y, e, 10}, Assumptions -> y > 0], 0 <= e <= 10}, e] // Simplify
```

> {1879/504 - Log[32], {e -> 0}}

```
N @ %
```

> {0.262439, {e -> 0.}}

although with warnings:

> Integrate::pwrl: "Unable to prove that integration limits {10,e} are real. Adding assumptions may help.

and

> Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a result on the boundary will be returned.

Let's investigate the procedure step by step:

---

First, compute the inner integral

```
f[y_] = Normal[Integrate[(((x - 5)/(10 - 5))^9*5)/x, {x, 5, y}]]
```

[image]

Without `Normal`, it's a `ConditionalExpression` with `y>0`. So, taking it into account in the outer integral:

```
g[e_] = Integrate[f[y]/
        (10 - e), {y, e, 10}, Assumptions -> y > 0 && 0 < e < 10]
```

[image]

where without `0 < e < 10` it is also a `ConditionalExpression` with this condition.

For visual inspection

```
Plot[g[e], {e, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

hence the maximum might indeed be at `e = 0` (or `e = 10`), but `g[0]` yields `Indeterminate` (`g[10]` yields `ComplexInfinity`), so

```
Limit[g[e], e -> 0]
Limit[g[e], e -> 10]
```

> `1879/504 - 5 Log[2]`
>
> `1879/504 - 5 Log[2]`

So the function does not have a local maximum in `0 < e < 10`; it reaches its (finite) maximal values only asymptotically at the boundaries of the interval.

So, wrapping it up, this

```
Maximize[{Integrate[1/(10 - e)
         Integrate[((x - 5)/(10 - 5))^(9)*5/x, {x, 5, y}]
       , {y, e, 10}, Assumptions -> y > 0 && 0 < e < 10], 
   0 <= e <= 10}, e] // Simplify
```

gives the proper answer, with a warning due to the limit. Constraining `e` to `9 <= e <= 10` in the last expression confirms that at `e->0` and `e->10` the expression yields the same value.

---

Additionally,

```
Minimize[{Integrate[1/(10 - e)
         Integrate[((x - 5)/(10 - 5))^(9)*5/x, {x, 5, y}]
       , {y, e, 10}, Assumptions -> y > 0 && 0 < e < 10], 
   0 <= e <= 10}, e] // N
```

> {0.0156124, {e -> 1.76903}}

without warnings (without `N` the output is a complicated and uninsightful `Root` expression).

Comment: I voted it up now and marked as solved. Thats my solution for now:  Maximize[{Integrate[1/(10 - e)
      Integrate[((x - a)/(10 - a))^(5)*5/x, {x, a, y}]
     - e^2, {y, Re[e], 10}], e >= 0, e <= 10, y \[Element] Reals}, 
  e \[Element] Reals] // N