# Any faster way to compute this?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

`Reduce` and `Solve` work for simpler functions than `j[e, n, b]`. I worked in your past advices.

Is there any better way to write it?

```
 h[e_, n_, b_, y_] := Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, 
      Normal[Integrate[((s - e)/(b - e))^(n - 1)*5/s, {s, e, y}]]]

 j[e_, n_, b_] := Integrate[1/(b - e)^2*h[e, n, b, y], {y, e, b}]

Reduce[j[e, n, 10.0] == 2e && e >= 0 && e <= 10 && n > 1 && n ∈ Integers, e] // N

Solve[j[e, n, 10.0] == 2e && e >= 0 && e <= 10.0 && n > 1.0 && n ∈ Integers, {e, n}]
```

Even after seperation i can't solve or reduce the problem.

Comment: Breaking the integrations in steps and pre-computing them (like in your [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130591/variable-integration-limits-over-real-numbers-only)) might shed some light.

Comment: I tried the speration following the other post but failed miserably :-(

Comment: `h[e_, n_, b_, y_] := 
 Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, 
  Normal[Integrate[((s - e)/(b - e))^(n - 1), {s, e, y}]]]
j[e_, n_, b_] := Integrate[1/(b - e)^2*5/y*h[e, n, b, y], {y, e, b}]` ?
Then, `f[2, 2, 10]` is equal to `j[2, 2, 10]`

Comment: Thx a lot.I still don#t see why it crashed for me.

Comment: Even after correclty seperating now, neither solve or reduce can do the trick :-(

Comment: Can anyone help me here? Or is this thing too complicated for mathematica?